# Overcome 50,000 number of article limit

Tags: governorlimits, limits, knowledge, articles

My company has around 80,000 articles, but salesforce has the limit of 50,000 articles. Is there way to overcome this using salesforce only. these article have information about diffirent products information.

Please advise.

Comment: You should reach out to your account rep or open a case to see if they will increase it. Usually these *limits* are not hard and fast if you simply ask.

Comment: Add a WHERE clauses to your query to narrow the scope of what you're looking for and you'll return less than 50,000 articles. Tell us what your use case is or what you're trying to do and post the query you're having difficulties with. In a batch class you can return far more than 50,000 articles (50 million).

Comment: @crmprogdev I think they are referring to `Maximum number of articles: 50,000 articles` on page 17 of the [Salesforce Developer Limits Quick Reference](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/20/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf).

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, I know the maximum is 50k for a single query. The question wasn't clear and that's why I asked him to clarify the use case.

Comment: Well, they can't store >50K records, so they can't possibly pull down >50K records in a single query. Still, I agree it could be a little more clear. @deva, can you please [edit] your post to verify which limit you are asking about?

Comment: @crmprogdev I am asking about the 50,000 articles limit, not the query limit.